# Is SSH enabled on a minimal ubuntu server installation?

Tags: ubuntu, system-installation, serial-port, serial-console

I recently bought an [APU2](https://www.pcengines.ch/apu2d4.htm) machine from PC Engines and installed Ubuntu 18.04 on it. The APU2 has no graphics output and I had to modify the [netboot ubuntu installation](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/main/installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/) to redirect the graphics output to the serial console. Essentially, I had to use an old XP machine with a serial console and connect the APU2 to this machine via a null modem cable. Then boot the APU2 using a TinyCore USB disk with the minimal ubuntu install on it. The installation went without a hitch. However, now the machine boots but nothing shows on the serial console. How do I now access this server? I did set a username and password while installing the machine. I tried accessing the machine via SSH but could not and got a `connection refused` message.

Comment: When you installed at first did you add ssh server? Also do you have a console access to the machine without ssh?

Comment: Welcome to [unix.se]!  **:-)** You're talking about TinyCore OS and Ubuntu.  Which of the 2 did you install?

Comment: @Panagiotis I don't think so. I do have access to the machine's file system though...

Comment: @Fabby Thank you :-) I booted using the TinyCore but installed Ubuntu.

Comment: I'm afraid you will need a serial console access again, and redo the setup for ubuntu and try to install ssh server as well (if it's the text installation then you should find it in the pre-grub setup)

Comment: Like @Panagiotis said, but I would boot and install from USB using the [Ubuntu minimal install ISO](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD).  Panagiotis, as you were first, do you want to answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you should select ssh server from software selection menu.

Selection menu screen is as follows:

https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-KekDjYsl9eY/W31Ym_9PLvI/AAAAAAAABbQ/wKaqi1YXcq4uZMAjY5hd5m2xkPUM3-KIACLcBGAs/s640/ubuntu1804-unity-install_2.png

I can see that this is a remarkable piece of hardware you are using (first time I hear it).... nice!

Comment: Yep this is what I did. Had to reinstall with the OpenSSH server selected and installed. Can access the machine with SSH now. It really is an awesome piece of hardware. A little tedious to set it up but quite awesome.

Comment: I am experimenting with arduino and raspberry pi3. A long time ago I was working with z80/6502, atMega and x86 platforms for assembly (studied hardware as a major in computer engineering). It's always a pleasure finding out new hardware boards :)